# How to reshape a list

Tags: list, ocaml

So consider getting a list of `[1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9]` and reshape it into `[[1; 2; 3]; [4; 5; 6]; [7; 8; 9]]`. How would you do that in OCaml? I want a simple function or something from the standard library.

Comment: This isn't a code writing service. You might want to try ChatGPT or Mechanical Turk instead for that. Otherwise, see [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) and [ask].

Comment: @glennsl Oof, I'm not familiar with that second tool so I won't comment on it, but we are very much not to the point of ChatGPT being a good tool for beginners to *learn* from. It's not even very good for *experienced* devs who can verify everything it says.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Sorry, I wasn't being very serious. The point is just that isn't about platform for doing one's homework, and just posting the problem description more or less verbatim isn't nearly sufficient. As described in the links I referred  to, more effort should be put into the question and it ought to be more specific.

Comment: Like a little reminder about how I started using ocaml 2 days ago and how I'm a hobbyist programmer and I'm following these stuff out of my own interest

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, it can be easily done with 3 lines of code, considering that the length of the list is divisible by 3.

```ml
let rec re_shape = function
| x :: xs :: xz :: xt -> [x; xs; xz] :: re_shape xt
| _ -> []
```

How this works is that for each iteration it cons a list of 3 to the rest of the function, till it reaches the end. The last line is added for safety.

Comment: Your first case is useless (you can just remove it), and your last case is wrong (it should be `[]`, not `[[]]`).

Comment: Interesting! I did that at first and it didn't work, but now it does. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As you have shown an effort to solve this, for your consideration, see *a* strategy below for generalizing this to allow for any length.

The `partition` function will allow us to get the first `n` elements from the list and the remainder, raising `Invalid_argument` if there aren't `n` elements in the list.

The `chunks` function applies this recursively to the remainder to build a list of lists.

```
let partition n lst =
  let rec partition' n (first, rest) =
    match n, rest with  
    | 0, _ -> (List.rev first, rest)
    | _, [] -> invalid_arg "List not long enough"
    | _, x::xs -> partition' (n-1) (x :: first, xs)
  in
  partition' n ([], lst)
  
let rec chunks n lst =
  match partition n lst with  
  | first, [] -> [first]
  | first, rest -> first :: chunks n rest
  | exception (Invalid_argument _) ->
    invalid_arg @@ Format.sprintf "List length not evenly divisible by %d" n
```

This second function is *not* tail-recursive, though that can readily be addressed in OCaml 4.14 and later with:

```
let[@tail_mod_cons] rec chunks n lst =
  ...
```